# Hosting WCF 3.5 on AppFabric

Tags: wcf, appfabric

I am planning to host the WCF services for one of my project on App Fabric. When i installed App Fabric it asked me to install the .Net Framework 4.0. I Can able to configure the WCF services written in 3.5 on App Fabric but i have to select the Asp.Net v4 as an App Pool. I feel the it using CLR 4.0 for the service.

Question is can i host my WCF 3.5 service on App Fabric as we are developing the solution in 3.5 and there is not much scope to migration to 4.0. Will is work?

Answer (score 2):

The first release of Windows Server AppFabric has two parts:

AppFabric Caching Services, which can speed up access to frequently accessed information such as session data used by an ASP.NET application.

AppFabric Hosting Services, making it easier to run and manage services created with Windows Communication Foundation, especially those built using Windows Workflow Foundation.

Looks like you can not use hosting services in 3.5.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637712.aspx

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/hosting-net-framework-3-x-services-in-appfabric.aspx

As far as caching goes it depends on the version, this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff381375.aspx#_Toc247686147 states:

NOTE: Beginning with the Beta2 version, the .NET framework requirements will change as follows. The Cache Service will require .NET 4.0 to be installed and Cache Clients developed using .NET 3.5 SP1 will be supported.

Answer (score 1):

AppFabric only works from .net 4.0, see:

http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2010/04/29/appfabric-and-net-framework-dependencies.aspx